# WCF - deploy certificates

Tags: wcf, ssl, certificate

I work on a solution involving multiple WCF business services.
One central server, unique, hosts one of them.
Several other machines (not known at development time) host other services. These machines will call the service hosted on the central server, and the central server will call the services hosted on these machines.
All the services are TCP/IP, and secured with X-509 certificates.
During development I use self-signed certificates, and it works great ; my question is about deploying in production environment : I've never done that before, and I dn't know how to handle that :
- can I buy a unique certificate, and deploy it on all machines ?
- must I buy a brand new certificate for each machine ?
- are there any safe alternatives ?

Thanks..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the domain name of all the servers are same, then you only have to generate a single SSL certificate and install it on every machine which are hosting your services. Otherwise, you have to generate SSL certificate for all the domains names and install it on respective machines.

If you have central server on different domain name and other servers on a different domain name(with domain name being same for other servers, differentiated by sub domain names).
Then, if you have 3 other machines server with same domain name but different sub domain names like **a.domain.com**, **b.domain.com** and **c.domain.com** and a central server. Now, instead of having 3 SSL certificates for **a.domain.com**, **b.domain.com** and **c.domain.com** on central server, you can purchase a wildcard SSL certificate which will serve requests from all the 3 machines.

Comment: Thanks Manish ; all machines will be on the same business network, BUT not on same domain. The service requests will be executed against the machine's ip, not dns (ex. wcf client will call "10.123.123.1:6789/myservice"). So i'll have to purchase a certificate for each machine, right ?

Comment: Yes, then you have to purchase certificate for each machine.

Comment: I noticed that when I tried to install the app on another computer, I just made an export of my self-signed certificate, added it on the other computer and it was able to communicate with my dev machine (= I did not used makecert on the other computer to create a new certificate).
Is it possible to purchase only one certificate, add it as root certificate on the central web server, then export it on other machines ? Or it worked only because it was a self-signed one ?

Comment: @Romka....you have to try it out, but I think it worked because of self-signed certificate. And as you said, your central server may request services from other servers and vice versa, I don't think a root certificate on only Central server will fix the issue.